# Which calls can the Client Token of a Facebook App be used for?

Tags: facebook

In the *Settings > Advanced* section of the Facebook App config there is a setting called **Client Token**. The description says *The Client Token is for auth methods in place of the app secret*.

[image: Client Token setting]

In what calls can the Client Token be used instead of the App Secret and why should it?

Comment: i didnt find client token here? where should i get client token?

Answer (score 2):

The client token is used for the client applications that cannot use the standard oAuth2 method.

A web application can fill the redirect_uri parameter ensuring that the calling url is the authorized url for the application, but an iOS application does not have a valid url to redirect to, so the client token is used instead.